# Nodejs Server is Running and localhost didn’t send any data on express project

Tags: node.js, express, passport-local

I working on Building a shopping cart Using Node.js Express and mongodb, using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHNLWHGCBEc&t=1167s), and so far there is no problem, but now when i run the server, it shows '

> Server running on port 3000

' But the problem is when I connect to localhost:3000 it shows,

> This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I check some error logs but didn't work. DB connection is also working, and DB has fetching data

There is no error shown in the terminal, How to solve this

my bin/www code

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('shopping-cart:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

my app.js code

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
require('./config/passport');

// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs',expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'mysupersecert', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));
app.use(flash);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

my index.js code

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('passport');

var Products = require('../models/product');

var csurfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csurfProtection);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Products.find(function (err, docs) {
    var productChunks = [];
    var chunkSize = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
      productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize))
    }
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks });

  });
});

router.get('/user/signup', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/signup',{csrfToken: req.csrfToken()})
});

router.post('/user/signup',passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
  successRedirect: 'user/profile',
  failureRedirect: 'user/signup',
  failureFlash: true

}));

router.get('user/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/profile')
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my passport.js code

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id,function (error, user) {
        done(err, user)
    })
});

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    userNameFeild: 'email',
    passwordFeild: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email Already in use'})
        }
        var newUser = User;
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
        })
    })
}));
```

and my product.js code

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('product', schema);
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your call to Products.find in index.js returns nothing the code doesn’t complete the http transaction.

Suggest you test for that case and complete the transaction with res.end()

Comment: tested with res.end()  but not solved yet, and thanks for your concern @vorpal